# ServiceStack.Text deserialize string into single object null reference

Tags: c#, .net, json, servicestack

I have the following code. With JSON.NET it works fine where I can deserialize the string into the CustomMaker object. With ServiceStack.Text I get null. I've tried doing  { get; set; } and removing and adding the constructor.

With JSON.NET it simply worked like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(xString);

Any idea why this does not  work with ServiceStack.Text?

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string xString = "{\"error\":\"Invalid token 1 #556264\"}";
        Console.WriteLine(xString);
        CustomMaker xSLBM = TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<CustomMaker>(xString);
        Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xSLBM.error) ? "error is null" : xSLBM.error);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CustomMaker {
        public int UserID;
        public String error;
        public CustomMaker() { }
    }
```

edit: This code also produces null:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
        string xString = "{\"error\":\"Invalid token 1 #556264\"}";
        Console.WriteLine(xString);
        CustomMaker xSLBM = TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString<CustomMaker>(xString);
        Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xSLBM.error) ? "error is null" : xSLBM.error);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CustomMaker {
        public CustomMaker() { }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public String error { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default ServiceStack only serializes **public properties** so you could refactor your DTO to include properties, e.g:

```
public class CustomMaker {
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public String error { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you wanted to serialize public fields you can specify this with:

```
JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```

Also you need to use the `JsonSerializer` class, e.g:

```
CustomMaker xSLBM = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<CustomMaker>(xString);
```

Or `string.ToJson()` or `T.FromJson<T>(string)` extension methods, e.g:

```
CustomMaker xSLBM = xString.FromJson<CustomMaker>();
```

The `TypeSerializer` class is only for serializing/deserializing the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/mythz_blog/blob/master/pages/176.md), not JSON.

Comment: I've already tried the property method, this code also produces null.

Comment: @CowKing see my update, you need to use the `JsonSerializer` class or `ToJson/FromJson` extension methods.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I guess the error was my fault in not understanding the difference between JSON and JSV.